# Baby Rudin Theorem 5.5 (Chain rule): What's wrong with the obvious proof?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

In Theorem 5.5, Rudin proves the chain rule, but does so in a somewhat different fashion than expected. It seems we can prove the chain rule more easily.

Theorem:
Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous  on $[a,b]$ and $g:I\to\mathbb{R}$ where $I$ is an interval that contains the range of $f$ and $g$ is continuous at $f(x)$. Then if we define $h(t)=g(f(t))$, $t\in[a,b]$, then $h'(x)=g'(f(x))f'(x)$.

Proof:
If we write down $g'(f(x))f'(x)$, it looks like we're done if we can just express $g'$ in terms of the same limits as $f'$, i.e., $\lim_{t\to x} g(f(t))=\lim_{y\to f(x)} g(y)$. Showing this seems equivalent to Theorem 4.7, that $h$ is continuous at $x$, but I'll write it for the sake of completeness:

$\lim_{y\to f(x)}g(y)=g(f(x)),$ so $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists\delta>0$ st $\forall y\in I$ st $d(y,f(x))<\delta, d(g(y),g(f(x)))<\epsilon$.

Since $f$ is continuous at $x$, $\exists \eta>0$ st $\forall t\in[a,b]$ st $d(t,x)<\eta,$ $d(f(t),f(x))<\delta$,which means $d(g(f(t)),g(f(x)))<\epsilon$.

So then $\lim_{t\to x} g(f(t)) = \lim_{y\to f(x)}g(y)$.

Then we have $g'(f(x))*f'(x) = \lim_{y\to f(x)}\frac{g(y)-g(f(x))}{y-f(x)}*\lim_{t\to x}\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}$
$=\lim_{t\to x}\frac{g(f(t))-g(f(x))}{f(t)-f(x)}*\lim_{t\to x}\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}$
$=\lim_{t\to x}\frac{g(f(t))-g(f(x))}{t-x} = h'(x)$.

Is there an issue to this approach I'm not seeing?

Comment: The issue of potential division by zero has arisen numerous times elsewhere on site, e.g., [Trouble understanding chain rule proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045776/trouble-understanding-chain-rule-proof); is that the question?

Comment: Yes, [this is a more direct and thorough treatment of the problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208234/on-the-wrong-proof-of-the-chain-rule).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, the issue is division by zero. To get around it, you can prove it as Rudin does (which can easily be [generalized](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3785633/568204) to higher dimensions), or you can define the 'modified difference quotients': $\phi:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$, and  $\gamma:I\to\Bbb{R}$ as
\begin{align}
\phi(t):=
\begin{cases}
\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}&\text{if $t\neq x$}\\
f'(x)&\text{if $t=x$}
\end{cases}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\gamma(s)&:=
\begin{cases}
\frac{g(s)-g(f(x))}{s-f(x)}&\text{if $s\neq f(x)$}\\
g'(f(x))& \text{if $s=f(x)$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
The benefit now is that these guys are defined everywhere, and furthermore, the fact that $f$ is differentiable at $x$, and $g$ is differentiable at $f(x)$ (by hypothesis) implies that the functions $\phi,\gamma$ are continuous at $x$ and $f(x)$ respectively. Now,
for any $t\neq x$, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{(g\circ f)(t)-(g\circ f)(x)}{t-x}&=\gamma(f(t))\cdot \phi(t).
\end{align}
To prove this, we consider two cases: the first case is if $f(t)-f(x)=0$; in this case, both sides are $0$, and in the second case, $f(t)-f(x)\neq 0$, you can multiply and divide by it. Now, $\gamma,f,\phi$ are continuous at the correct points, so we can take the limit $t\to x$ to get that the limit is $\gamma(f(x))\cdot \phi(x)=g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

You have to take care not to divide by zero. Think of functions like $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ that are differentiable at $0$ and vanish at a sequence tending to $0$.